# around plugin overriding other before plugins

Tags: magento2, vendor

In the vendor module, I have a plugin for some methods. I'd like to add a before plugin for this method but it looks like this is around from the vendor overriding all other plugins (before and after). This vendor plugin does not call proceed(). Is there any way to add a before plugin in this case?

I know that I can just disable the vendor plugin in my di.xml and add my own around plugin build from this vendor code and mine code. Or add a preference for this vendor plugin. Or maybe a plugin for plugin beforeAround... ? But it all looks strange I think. Or maybe not?

SOLVED:
I added (override) in my di.xml lower sortOrder for this vendor plugin and higher at my plugin. Now it works :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can add beforeAroundThatMethodName() plugin so that it will be executed before that around plugin